# unknown profile in visual studio

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I wanted to update my devices in a provisioning profile by adding 2 more (Iphone 6 and 8)
like image bellow :

[image: 2 devices added]

Here is profile :

[image: provisionning profile]

And cetificate from my MAC :

[image]

After updating that I downloaded again certificates and profiles but when clicking on downloaded profile I got this error

> Xcode encountered an error

What I have to do because now Xamarin forms app set profile to unknown :

[image: xamarin forms seetings app]

Should I have to remove all certificates and profile and try again and I noticed that there is a lot of profiles that i can't be show you but why is there just one in visual studio

**SOLUTION**

- I removed all profiles in Xcode folders
- I removed all profiles in web developer web site
- I removed all certificates in keychains
- I removed all certificates in web developer web site
- Just recreate certificates and profiles

I noticed that when we want to add devices to profiles I should edit profiles, add devices. After, we I have to remove profiles and re-install them.

Comment: Make sure that the version of Xcode and VS are up-to-date .This is seems the issuein Xcode 11.2.1 and you could  logged in the accounts and download manual profile .

Comment: I already tried to install profile using download manual profile, however my visual studio is not up-to-date. I tell you when it will be finish. Thank you ! @LucasZhang-MSFT

Comment: Before I used a MAC that is not contains visual studio but it work's well when I use MAC coupler, so I have to install visual studio or xcode is sufficient ?

Comment: Update the Xcode firstly.

Comment: Xcode is up-to-date V11.3

Comment: Do you talk about account in visual, xcode or phone ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205673/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-wyllismonteiro).

Comment: I'm into the discussion

Comment: Try to delete the apple account in VS and add it again .

Comment: ok, but I would like to understand something, for iOS I need to use a MAC and generate certificates and should I have the project ?